Why a class derived from unordered_map need operator== definition?
#include <unordered_map>

#define LIBRARY
#if defined(LIBRARY)
#  define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


struct Base {
    double d1;
    double d2;
    double d3;
    /* It can be built if I uncommon the following code. */ 
    //bool operator==(const Base& rhs) const {
    //    return true;
    //}
};

struct EXPORT Derived : public std::unordered_map<int, Base> {};

int main() {
    Derived d;

    return 0;
}

here is the output tab information:
1>D:\VS2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\xhash(246,8):
1>see declaration of 'std::_Hash_vec<std::allocator<std::_List_unchecked_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>>>>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=std::pair<const int,Base>
1>        ]
1>D:\VS2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\utility(491,56): error C2676: binary '==': 'const _Ty2' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
1>D:\VS2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\utility(491,56): error C2676:         with
1>D:\VS2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\utility(491,56): error C2676:         [
1>D:\VS2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\utility(491,56): error C2676:             _Ty2=Base
1>D:\VS2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\utility(491,56): error C2676:         ]

There are two way to build this code.

define a const operator== explicitly.(Seems reasonable by looking at the error information
remove the EXPORT sign in Derived.

I mainly confused how does the EXPORT sign affect the building process?

Not the problem, but the way that you've written your code, EXPORT will always evaluate to __declspec(dllexport)...

Looking at the output from the compiler, it looks as though it's compiling a function in such a way that it thinks multiple elements are allowed (i.e. a multimap), in which case it needs a way to compare the second element. I'm unsure as to why it's doing that though, since you're using a unordered_map not a unordered_multimap

EXPORT needs to evaluate to __declspec(dllimport) when using the dll and __declspec(dllexport) when compiling the dll. That is the purpose of the macro.

Encounter C2676 At StackOverlow its important to copy and paste the exact text of the error message into the question. Not everyone will Google the error code to attempt to figure out what the problem is. The text in the "Output Tab" is best for this and not the text in the "Errors List" Also if your native language is not english please switch back to English to get the text.

@ChrisMM Hi. I am also confused by this too. I read the reference.  stl defined a non-member function(operator ==between two map) in unordered_map. But it still works if i explicitly delete the operator==. The only way the compiler generate this non-member function is I call the == function, then the building fails.

@drescherjm Thanks for your advise. I modified the question details and added output tab information

@drescherjm This code is only for simulating the library building process. It's reasonable  that this EXPORT always evaluate to __declspec(dllexport) here.

@ChrisMM So how to explain that this code is built sucessfully if I remove the EXPORT flag?

When you export, then the compiler will compile all functions within the class. If you don't export, then, because it's a template, it only compiles the ones you need.

@ChrisMM I'm wondering It there any reference or guide for this? In the other word, How do we know which functions will be export?
